# ¿Alguien sabe que significa este triangulo azul, en esta variable?. Es del IDE Eclipse, estoy trabajando con Java

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]¿Alguien sabe que significa este triangulo azul, en esta variable?. Es del IDE Eclipse, estoy trabajando con Java. Bueno, estoy trabajando con una clase de tipo Enum pero al momento de crear esa misma variable en la clase no se le puede asignar un valor del mismo tipo, por eso cree una variable dentro de la misma clase Circulo de tipo enum. Para poder asignar una de las opciones a esa variable. Pero no se que significa el circulo azul.

Comment: Sería de ayuda que compartieras una captura de lo que hablas e incluyeras los errores que aparezcan en la misma línea triángulo morado por si tienen alguna relación.

Comment: Según la [referencia de íconos](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm), indica que es un campo con visibilidad predeterminada.

Comment: Ese recuadro te informa el nombre completo de la variable: cuadro.circulo.Pointer, que de tipo opciones, simplemente y el icono, segun el color te dice si el public, private o protected.  En tu caso es private por lo que no podrás asignarle valor alguno en alguna otra clase hija o cualquier instancia alguna. La visibilidad predeterminada es private si mas no recuerdo. Esa variable no le has puesto si es public, protected o private